# ExtJS - Drag column header to other grid

Tags: extjs, grid, datagridcolumn

I need **keep** the default feature of reordering columns and add
possibility drop the column in a second grid, building in the last a list
with the columns of first grid.

I hope has been clear.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Show what you've tried.

Comment: I need to create a DropZone in another grid that receive the drag of column header from first grid, keeping the default reorder columns feature from the last grid.

I'm extending the DropZone and think that I'm on the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue extending DropZone. This implementation receive as constructor param the target grid, and this, be in the rbar (docked control) of source grid. The key is set ddGroup to "header-dd-zone-" plus id from source grid. I hope this is useful.

```
Ext.define('Crud.FilterDropZone', {
    extend: 'Ext.dd.DropZone'

    , constructor: function() {}

    , init: function (grid) {
        var me = this;

        if (grid.rendered) {
            me.grid = grid;
            me.ddGroup = 'header-dd-zone-' + grid.up('grid').id;
            grid.getView().on({
                render: function(v) {
                    me.view = v;
                    Crud.FilterDropZone.superclass.constructor.call(me, me.view.el);
                },
                single: true
            });
        } else {
            grid.on('render', me.init, me, {single: true});
        }
    }

    , getTargetFromEvent: function (e) {
        return {};
    }

    , onNodeDrop: function (nodeData, source, e, data) {
        var header = data.header
            , store = Ext.getCmp(e.target.id).getStore();

        //store.add(new store.RecordType({ property: header.text, value: '', reference: header.dataIndex}));
        store.add([[header.text, '', header.dataIndex]]);
    }

});
```